# Safest way to reference row ID for table

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, jquery

I've been wondering for a while now but I've yet to come up with a truly useful way of manipulating rows passed to the browser without exposing part of my DB. Basically what I want is a way to (1) Presenta table of elements retrieved from my database (2) Have the possibility to edit/delete my elements through AJAX.

Now my dilemma here is the fact that I'd ultimately have to pass an element's ID giving the user access to it and possibly changing the values giving him the opportunity to hack my database. So my question is: What would be the ideal way of presenting an edit/delete button that lets me use ajax to get to my element on the server without exposing it to the user?

Should I use a hidden row in the table? Query the original field values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A user isn't going to hack your database if you escape your data and check the user has access to the data that they are updating prior to committing said update.

I would like to recommend you look at Backbone (http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/) as it helps quite a bit with data manipulation.

Comment: Plus showing/hiding ID is only a matter of style. Hidden row in a table is just style. It won't stop a hacker. :) Escaping data, authorization and priviles, and some other protection (for example CSRF) is necessary.

Comment: Yeah - as a general principle I always consider my users to be my enemies when it comes to security. After all, one false move and their account information can get stolen.. they could get ticked at their boss and try some 'neat stuff they saw on die hard 4'.. etc :P